# change and display hostname of url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sites: one for an internal audience and one for an external audience. The site URLs will match other than the hostname. What I would like to do is have a button available on the internal site so that someone can click and be given the external URL of that page.

Essentially I want to replace the hostname of the current URL using javascript or jquery - whatever is quicker and easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect the current tab you can just set the hostname directly:

```
$( '#external-link' ).click( function ( ) {
    location.hostname = 'external-domain.com';
} );
```

If you want it to open in a new tab you can do something like this:

```js
$( '#external-link' ).click( function ( ) {
    this.href = '//external-domain.com' + location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
} );
```

```html
<a href="#" id="external-link" target="_blank">Open External Page</a>
```

Comment: Your href in the second snippet is invalid, you need to specify a protocol, otherwise it's interpreted as a relative address.

Comment: Whoops! @PatrickRoberts , I've fixed it now. Thank you for pointing that out.